# SF book involving a NASA/military scientist finding a statue in an archaeological dig on Earth

Tags: story-identification, books

I was browsing a book store within the past five years and read a blurb of a book on the SF section. I do not remember the author or title, but the plot was something along the lines of that in the question, and the book was written from the perspective of one of the investigators/scientists/military folk involved in the discovery. If I recall correctly, a large shiny metallic hand was unearthed, but the hand was postulated to be the tip. I think the book progressed as more of the thing was dug out.

I could be inaccurately remembering the blurb.

Comment: The answers below helped locate it. As I remember now, this was the cover image: https://www.scifinow.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Sleeping-Giants-Sylvain-Neuvel.png

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is [Sleeping Giants](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25733990-sleeping-giants) by Sylvain Neuval, first in a trilogy. Extract from Goodreads:

> A girl named Rose is riding her new bike near home in Deadwood, South Dakota, when she falls through the earth. She wakes up at the bottom of a square-shaped hole, its walls glowing with intricate carvings. But the firemen who come to save her peer down upon something even stranger: a little girl in the palm of a giant metal hand.
>
> Seventeen years later, the mystery of the bizarre artifact remains unsolved - the object's origins, architects, and purpose unknown.
>
> But some can never stop searching for answers.
>
> Rose Franklin is now a highly trained physicist leading a top-secret team to crack the hand's code. And along with her colleagues, she is being interviewed by a nameless interrogator whose power and purview are as enigmatic as the relic they seek. What's clear is that Rose and her compatriots are on the edge of unravelling history's most perplexing discovery-and finally figuring out what it portends for humanity. But once the pieces of the puzzle are in place, will the result be an instrument of lasting peace or a weapon of mass destruction?

Comment: Yes - this is the one! Thanks for locating it.

Answer (score 15):

Possibly [Sleeping Giants](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25733990-sleeping-giants) by Sylvain Neuvel:

> A girl named Rose is riding her new bike near home in Deadwood, South Dakota, when she falls through the earth. She wakes up at the bottom of a square-shaped hole, its walls glowing with intricate carvings. But the firemen who come to save her peer down upon something even stranger: a little girl in the palm of a giant metal hand.
>
> Seventeen years later, the mystery of the bizarre artifact remains unsolved - the object's origins, architects, and purpose unknown.
>
> But some can never stop searching for answers.
>
> Rose Franklin is now a highly trained physicist leading a top-secret team to crack the hand's code. And along with her colleagues, she is being interviewed by a nameless interrogator whose power and purview are as enigmatic as the relic they seek. What's clear is that Rose and her compatriots are on the edge of unravelling history's most perplexing discovery-and finally figuring out what it portends for humanity. But once the pieces of the puzzle are in place, will the result be an instrument of lasting peace or a weapon of mass destruction?

Comment: Yes - this is the one! Thanks for locating it.